# Checking if variables are contained in array

Tags: arrays, macos, applescript

I have an array with a series of IDs. After I get another array I'd like to check if each single value of it is contained in the main ID array. And if there's even one new ID set a variable to TRUE (I'm in a repeat cycle: "repeat until controller is TRUE").

How can I achieve that? I'm a newbie with Applescript and I don't know how to do these mass checking.

Comment: Applescript doesn't support arrays. Did you want to mean lists? Post your code if you have any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
set listA to {"A1", "A2", "A3"}
set listB to {"B1", "B2", "A3"}

set match to false
repeat with anItem in listB
    if anItem is in listA then
        set match to true
        exit repeat
    end if
end repeat

return match
```